# Reverse Engineering a specific bluetooth communication protocol

Tags: encryption, bluetooth, reverse-engineering, wireshark, sniffing

I have been reading answers on stackoverflow for a while now and this is the first time I actually am required to ask a question:

I have a small sensing device (literally a black box) which is used during sporting activities and is tracking acceleration and GPS data (not necessarily with the same frequency, according to a patent from the vendor). After a  session, one can connect the device to a smartphone and import the session data to view statistics.
Now I am trying to acquire the raw data to apply some own statistics onto it.

I know that the device connects to my phone via Bluetooth. So I activated the Bluetooth HCI snoop log following this tutorial:

http://www.fte.com/WebHelp/BPA600/Content/Documentation/WhitePapers/BPA600/Encryption/GettingAndroidLinkKey/RetrievingHCIlog.htm

I can then transfer the files by renaming them into .cap files on the PC and load them into wireshark. This is where it gets tricky:
I have found out, that the first connection is established via Bluetooth low energy. When the connection is established and the user has selected to download a session from the device via the app, the connection switches to a normal Bluetooth connection.
I know that the device contains a GPS and a 9-axis accelerometer including a Gyro.

Apparently the Bluetooth protocol to transfer data is the SPP protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Serial_Port_Profile_.28SPP.29), used to simulate a RS-232 connection.

I have attached a screenshot from wireshark showing a reassembled data packet. I do not know what it contains and the rendering from Wireshark does not make any sense to me. The frame content is displayed in the bottom most tab. The left is the raw HEX transmission, the right shows the rendered version. It neither looks like any GPS sentence (http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm), nor like any accelerometer data:

[image: Screenshot of the Wireshark UI]

The general setting is an encryption-less connection, but at some stage the host and controller try to switch to an encryption, but this never gets transmitted to the peripheral slave (as far as I can see). I am wondering how to make sense of this data, whether there is a way for me to find out whether an encryption is activated and if it is, is it logged and can I retrieve the key from this log?

Can anyone help me to figure out the data here or tell me where I can find some hints about whether it is encrypted or not?

**Edit:**
I have added a screenshot from the first SPP transmission packet.   [image: Screenshot of the first transmission packet]  The packet in question and the payload are marked in black. It seems to contain some information about device and other configuration settings or initial values for the sensors at the beginning. I suspect the app and the device to have settled on a *proprietary* scrambling or encrypting, since there are readable values at the beginning, but not after that black box marked in the image. My suspicion is, that bluetooth encryption is not being used at all and I therefore stand no chance of decrypting the information at all? Can someone confirm or deny this suspicion?

Comment: It's hard to confirm your suspicion, but of course is absolutely possible that they use encryption at application layer rather than using BLE encryption at link layer; or they may use both. To understand if they use BLE encryption, you must look for HCI commands indicating that; but that is irrelevant to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

> where I can find some hints about whether it is encrypted or not?

What you see in Wireshark is the HCI interface (commands and events) between Host and Controller. Since encryption is done in the controller (see Bluetooth Core spec. Vol. 1 Part A Section 5.4.3), what you see is **unencrypted** data.

> Can anyone help me to figure out the data here

It's hard to understand from your single screenshot. I suggest you take a look at the [RFCOMM specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=263754&_ga=2.65238311.827567838.1510001101-1596266107.1509217926), Figure 6.1 in paricular:

[image: RFCOMM frame structure.]

In the **Information** field you should find your data.